What is expected output?
Unexpected (for me) output.
The code is:
public  static async Task Main()
{
    Stopwatch  stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)            
        await Task.Delay(1);
    
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);                       
}


My best understanding is that output should be close to 1000. The reality is different. Can somebody explain why?
Thanks

You might want to flesh out what you mean by " should be close to 1000. The reality is different". Was it 3, 1001, perhaps 4500?

Also, you might not be able to wait 1 millisecond on your computer; it might be finer than the resolution of the timer used to do the waiting, which, if you're on standard Windows, is probably about 16ms. In practice this means that awaiting intervals that are not a multiple of about 16ms will be a few ms off as the interval rounds up to the next 16ms multiple. Awaiting 1 ms a thousand times might take around 16 seconds because. Do you need to wait for a very accurate amount of time?

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here. Task.Delay and Thread.Sleep just suspend execution for that long, at which point the kernel schedules something else to run on the CPU. There is absolutely no guarantee that the kernel will immediately reschedule your code as soon as it's runnable, there may be many other threads that have a higer priority. Combined that with an imprecise timer, and this whole test is a complete fallacy. Unless you placed this thread on Real Time Priorirty (the highest) then you can't even begin to test the timer's accuracy.

@Charlieface the main issue here is the imprecision of the timer, at the microsecond level. Normally a modern machine has enough cores to satisfy immediately requests for CPU work, most of the time. For example my PC rarely has a CPU usage of 100%, where thread priorities come to play.

If you are asking about why Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) is not near 1000, short answer is there is an overhead in creating async operations.
On my computer, running your code gives:
1160

I assume it is somehow you mean not close to 1000.
But if you do this instead of a loop:
await Task.Delay(1000);

On my computer it outputs:
1003

For details on async operation performance there is a good post explained it:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423005/measuring-async-await-overhead
Assuming the < 0.1ms overhead still true today. For easier calculation let's take 0.1ms to create an async task = 1000*0.1ms = 100ms. Which is close to my result of 1160 with your code.
A more in-depth article about async performance can be found here

@Zuprik glad to know how it works! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.
